# JQuery not populating into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I'm trying to understand why this isn't populating. newProblem() is set to run on initial button click so it's not the function itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zu7Lp9y/2/

HTML

```
<p class="number first-number" id="firstNumberDiv"></p>
```

JS/JQUERY

```
function newProblem(){
var x=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);


$("#firstNumberDiv").text(x);
}
```

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle with your code, please?

Comment: You have to call the function and the Element as to be defined before you run the jQuery.

Comment: The function is called on initial button click and the second half of the fucntion works, I'm just trying to get it to work with jquery and I can't get it.

Comment: what do you mean by the "element has to be defined before you run the jquery?"

Comment: @sgaglos element defined first means the javascript must be below the HTML creating firstNumberDiv, we cannot tell if it is in the `<head>`, or in the correct position in the `<body>`.  Code needs to be **complete** and this is insufficient to re-create the issue. Either create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or post a minimal version of the rest of the code. I recommend jsfiddle -  you can copy &  paste sections of code in until you have the shortest that reproduces the problem. The process of doing that also helps you debug the code, improving your debugging skills.

Comment: What's the problem? Can you give us further explanations? (more codes so we can understand your problem better, because I thought I answered that). Thanks.

Comment: Yea sorry this is my first time using jsfiddle. So what I'm trying to do is to populate a random number into the p tag. It will change dynamically, which I think I can handle, but for now I'm just trying to get it in there.

Comment: This is what the code did actually , and to see that, open the fiddle that i gave you in my answer, and click on "Run" button several times, and you'll see that the number in the preview changes every time. The number is between 0 and 10 (10 in not included)..

Comment: I understand, why doesn't work on button click though?

Answer (score 0):

You're just defining a function, but you should call it as well.

Like this :

```
$(document).ready(newProblem());
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/3zu7Lp9y/)